# Monitoring visited websites

Tags: java, google-chrome, monitoring

Is there any way for me to monitor the websites I visit in real time from a Java application? (I'm using Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome and other Google products and one of them is [`Web History`](https://www.google.com/history).

The Web History feature requires JavaScript in order to work correctly. And JavaScript must be enabled in one of these supported browsers:

- Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0 and newer
- Firefox
- Netscape 6.0 and newer
- Mozilla
- Safari 1.2 and newer
- Opera 7 and newer
- Google Chrome

I personally have not used it's API, but I do know it has RSS feed. You can read that RSS feed in Java.